# Plone/Workflow- Is it possible to set the state of a workflow without needing a transition?

Tags: workflow, plone

I have a content type (batch) that is tied to multiple instances of a different content (my_item) by an id.  The my_item content type has a workflow consisting of draft, pending, and approved.  There is a form that creates the batch and "approves" the my_item content type instances, and sets the my_item_instances' batch_id to the batch's batch id (set when the batch is created).  The approved state is a final state, where it cannot be edited nor retracted.

I need to be able to change the state of the my_item content type instances back to draft.  Since there is no transition for back to draft from the approved state when the item is being deleted (through a subscriber), I need to somehow set the state of the my_items back to "draft" without needing a transition.

There are two methods I tried:

The subscriber is IObjectWillBeRemoved

```
def my_item_will_be_removed(obj,event)
    my_items = catalog.searchResults('batch_id':obj.batch_id)
    for i in my_items:
        api.content.transition(obj=i,to_state='pending')
```

This results in an error
    InvalidParaemterError: Could not find workflow to set state to draft on

I also tried using:

```
wf_tool = api.portal.get_tool(name='portal_workflow')
wf_tool.setStatusOf('item_workflow',i,'pending')
```

For some reason that ends up with the my_item becoming a string.

Is it not possible?  If it is possible, how can I do so?

---

Offtopic, but I guess a workaround I could use for now is:
make a transition "retract_from_approval" that goes from the approved state to the draft state

'can_retract_from_approval' needs to be assigned to the role that can delete the "batch"

In the deletion event, iterate through the my_items, assign the 'can_retract_from_approval' permission to the role responsible for deleting the batch locally on the current iteration

```
my_items = catalog.searchResults('batch_id',obj.batch_id)
for m in my_items:
    mi_obj = m.getObject()
    mi_obj.manage_permission('retract_from_approval',['ARole'],obj=mi_obj)
```

Then use the workflow tool to do the 'retract_from_approval' transition that sends the my_item back into the draft state.  And then remove the 'can_retract_from_approval' permission.

Comment: Can you clarify "ends up with the `my_item` becoming a string"? Your code snippet iterates `i` over your items and then you call methods on `e`, but I guess that's a pasto?

Comment: Edit: I meanat to put e = i.getObject()

Comment: Update:  Sorry, I figured out I didn't use e = i.getObject().  So i was just the brain.  That was the problem.  I'm sorry it was the result of a typo.

Comment: I don't know if anyone else is thinking this, but since workflow is a FSM (Finite State Machine) - and an FSM is one of the fundamentals in computer science, asking to "break" it seems really wrong to me! I think your "workaround" is closer to the correct solution - though probably you should add an remove the role from the user/group rather than add/remove permissions to the role.  Though I would question why you can't leave them alone and hand out permissions very carefully

Comment: I admit this is an odd case.  I should've mentioned pending instead of draft.  The only time my_item is supposed to be set to approved is when it is batched with other my_items.  In order to maintain "integrity" for what we're doing, approved my_items can't be modified at all and the batch has to be deleted as opposed to just "uncoupling" my_items from the batch.  I am probably going to end up giving the Manager role the ability to retract.  Then when a batch is deleted, in the event assign the role locally, do the transaction, unassign the local role.  Its just in case batched items werewrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a snippet of an old migration tool I used for migrate from Plone 2.5 to Plone 3 *a lot* of years ago.

```
    wtool = getToolByName(obj, 'portal_workflow')
    status = {'action': '', 
              'review_state': old_state, 
              'actor': 'admin', 
              'comments': 'Recovery state', 
              'time': DateTime() }

    wtool.setStatusOf(workflow_id, obj, status)
```

1. not sure if it still works nowadays
2. you probably need a `reindexObjectSecurity`

Comment: Thank you for your response.  This answer actually takes care of other questions I would've/might've had in the future.  Thank you.

Comment: The permissions don't seem to be working properly after the transition, even after using reindexObjectSecurity (obj.reindexObjectSecurity()).  In the state I'm sending it back to, the user originally had the 'Delete objects' permission (as defined in my workflow) that allowed them to delete objects stored inside the my_item, but after transitioning it back to the state with this method they don't have the permissions they should have.  For now I can use manage_permission (obj.manage_permission('Delete objects',roles=[...]))